# How do I listen to uncaught errors while loading an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

I develop web content meant to be embedded into `iframe`s for my current job. In order to test this content, I have created a small web app that simulates the environment they'll be deployed in and reports problems and errors about them. One way in which I report errors is by listening to the `"error"` event of the `iframe`'s `contentWindow` with `addEventListener` and printing the error message to a sort of error log in the app.

This works most of the time, however the event doesn't get triggered if errors happen while loading the `iframe`'s content, such as a function called on the body's onload callback. This happens because I subscribe to the `"load"` event of the `iframe` and set the error callback at that point, meaning the error event probably gets triggered before loading is finished. I've already tried listening to the `iframe`'s `"error"` event to bypass this, but this doesn't seem to work either, and I'm not sure what else I can try. How can I report these errors if they happen before content loading is finished?

Here's what my code looks like for listening to errors. `console.log` would normally be replaced with my custom logging function in the app.

```
const iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
iframe.addEventListener("load", () => {
    iframe.contentWindow.addEventListener("error", ev => {
        console.log(`${iframe.src.slice(iframe.src.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)} ${ev.lineno}:${ev.colno} - ${ev.message}`);
    }, true);
});
```